# Did the form of address of female officers and crew of Startrek change over the years?

Tags: star-trek

This question is prompted by the latest of a long series of questions on English Language and Usage about gender neutral terms in English.  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386956/chairman-chairwoman-or-chairperson

I seem to remember that Captain Janeway was called "Sir", but I have a broader question than about that particular point: did Startrek change over the years, from the first TGO episodes filmed to the recent films about the alternate universe, in how women officers were addressed when their rank was not the means of address?  (Female officers certainly changed in how they were *dressed*!)

Comment: There is no point beyond Voyager. With the exception of a few tiny instances where the crew jump into the future, we don't see anything beyond Voyager: Endgame.

Comment: (The question itself on the proposed duplicate answers this question; female officers were always addressed as "sir" except for Janeway, and that was just a personal idiosyncrasy.)